# MPDF Fatal error: Interface 'Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface' not found

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to use MPDF  but when loading it I get the following error, does anyone know why?https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

[image]

My Code

```
 <?php 

  require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf/src/Mpdf.php';

  $mpdf = new mPDF('c','A4');
  $mpdf->writeHTML('<div>HELLO WORLD</div>'); 
  $mpf->Output('new.pdf','I');

  ?>
```

Comment: How did you acquire mpdf? From Github or composer?

Comment: Github, in the usage guide it says require_once __DIR__. '/vendor/autoload.php'; but I can not find that route (start trying it today, because I want to implement it in my project)

Comment: I would suggest you follow the installation instruction found on the readme: https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf otherwise you will have to manage the dependencies and drive yourself crazy

Comment: I'm supposed to create a JSON file using this ... I'd like to run it from Composer ... but I do not understand what I'm supposed to write inside ... could you help me with the JSON please?  I use windows  7 https://packagist.org/packages/mpdf/mpdf#v7.0.0-RC3

Comment: Follow instructions on composer documentation website https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows

Answer (score 3):

There are two points.
1: go to your php.ini file and uncomment the ;extension=gd
remove semicolon from start.
2: run the command `composer require mpdf/mpdf v8.1.2 -W`.

This works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there will be a compatibility issue with the package (mpdf) version and the language(PHP) version After several attempts, the compatibility between Jazm and language(PHP) was discovered as follows.

- mPDF >=7.0 is supported on PHP ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0
- PHP 7.3 is supported since mPDF v7.1.7
- PHP 7.4 is supported since mPDF v8.0.4
- PHP 8.0 is supported since mPDF v8.0.10
- PHP 8.1 is supported as of mPDF v8.0.13

If you have trouble installing the package, use the following command

```
composer require mpdf/mpdf:^version -w
```

Note: Put the word “version” instead (the version that matches your version)

Good luck everyone......

Answer (score -1):

are you using mpdf ver 7?
if yes, you can change your code to

```
require_once APPPATH.'/third_party/mpdf7/vendor/autoload.php';
return new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

ref: https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html